# простая сетка на scss maps

Tags: css3, sass, scss

Пытаюсь изобрести простую сетку на scss maps и миксинах.
**Задумка**: есть класс `.grid` добавляем ему миксин
`+grid((def: 12, lg: 4, md: 6), (def: 20, lg: 10 xs: 0), breakpoints)`

Где в обоих мапах `key` - это `media` разрешение , которое мы сверяем с `breakpoints` (`def` - значение по умолчанию). В первой мапе `value` означает кол-во колонок, а во второй отступы между колонками.

На выходе должен получится `классКоторомуПрописанМиксин__item` с дефолтным значениям взятым с `def` и сгенерированными медиа запросами взятые с соответствующих аргументов.

**Реализация:**

```css
$breakpoints: (
  xl: 1440px,
  lg: 1200px,
  md: 992px,
  xs: 768px,
  sm: 576px,
);

@mixin grid($grid-map, $gap-map: (def: $grid-gap), $grid-breakpoints: $breakpoints) {
  // $c: & - это сам класс, которому мы задаем стили т.е если .grid  - то айтем будет .grid__item
  $c: &;
  @at-root {
    #{$c} {
      display: flex;
      flex-flow: row wrap;
      @include grid-gap($gap-map, $container: true)
    };
    #{$c}__item {
      @each $breakpoint, $value in $grid-map {
        @include check-breakpoints($breakpoint) {
          width: 100%;
          max-width: percentage(1 / 12 * $value);
        }
      }
      @include grid-gap($gap-map)
    }
  }
}

//отступ - если это .grid - то у него отрицательный margin , если .grid__item то padding
@mixin grid-gap($gap-map, $container: false) {
  @each $breakpoint, $value in $gap-map {
    @include check-breakpoints($breakpoint) {
      @if $container == true {
        @if $value == 0 {
          margin: 0;
        } @else {
          margin: 0 -#{$value}px;
        }
      } @else {
        @if  $value == 0 {
          padding: 0;
        } @else {
          padding: 0 #{$value}px;
        }
      }
    }
  }
}

//сверяем ключ в переданной карте и карте брейпоинтов если есть, то берем значение данного брейкпоинта.
@mixin check-breakpoints($breakpoint, $g-breakpoints: $breakpoints) {
  @if $breakpoint == 'def' {
    @content;
  }
  @else {
    @if map-has-key($g-breakpoints, $breakpoint) {
      $breakpoint: map-get($g-breakpoints, $breakpoint);
    }
    @media (max-width: $breakpoint) {
      @content
    }
  }
}
```

**Всё работает, но** на выходе дублируется `.grid__item` из-за двух итераций(самой сетки и отступов) пробовал делать отступы и кол-во колонок в одной мапе, но тогда теряем гибкость миксина, т.е нужно каждый раз писать и кол-во колонок и кол-во отступов.

```css
.grid {
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: row wrap;
  margin: 0 -20px;
}

.grid__item {
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 100%;
  padding: 0 20px;
}

@media (max-width: 1200px) {
  .grid {
    margin: 0 -10px;
  }
  
  /* дублируется класс
  .grid__item {
    width: 100%;
    max-width: 33.33333%;
  }

  .grid__item {
    padding: 0 10px;
  }
  */
}

@media (max-width: 992px) {
  .grid__item {
    width: 100%;
    max-width: 50%;
  }
}

@media (max-width: 768px) {
  .grid {
    margin: 0;
  }

  .grid__item {
    padding: 0;
  }
}
```